# Wait for all the AsyncTask called in a loop are finished?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm calling async tasks in a loop on the onPostExecute() of an asyncTask. I want the control to wait until response of all the tasks is not receieved cause I'm collecting the response in a  single arrayList which i have to pass a callback method after all the asyncTasks called in the loop are finished.

I'm avoiding to use the AsyncTask.get() as it blocks the main thread.

```
public class CallServerAsync extends AsyncTask<AsyncHttpRequestBo, Void, ArrayList<ArrayList<AsyncHttpRequestBo>>> implements PlatwareResponseListener {
PlatwareClientCommonUtils clientCommonFunctions;
Context context;
String url;
PlatwareResponseListener listener;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
ArrayList<AsyncHttpResponseBo> processResponseList = null;
ArrayList<AsyncHttpResponseBo> responseList = null;

public CallServerAsync(Context context, PlatwareResponseListener listener) {
    this.context = context;
    clientCommonFunctions = new PlatwareClientCommonUtils(context);
    url = clientCommonFunctions.getServerUrlPrimary();
    this.listener = listener;
    responseList = new ArrayList<AsyncHttpResponseBo>();
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please wait", "Downloading...");
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<ArrayList<AsyncHttpRequestBo>> doInBackground(AsyncHttpRequestBo... params) {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<AsyncHttpRequestBo>> requestLists = clientCommonFunctions.generateRequestList(params);
    return requestLists;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ArrayList<AsyncHttpRequestBo>> result) {

    for (ArrayList<AsyncHttpRequestBo> httpRequestList : result) {
        CallserverSubAsync callserverSubAsync = new CallserverSubAsync(context, this);
        callserverSubAsync.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, httpRequestList);
        // ArrayList<AsyncHttpResponseBo> processResponseList = null;
        // try {
        // processResponseList = callserverSubAsync.get();
        // } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // }

    }
    listener.onAsyncTaskCompleted(responseList, listener);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    super.onCancelled();
}

@Override
public void onAsyncTaskCompleted(ArrayList<AsyncHttpResponseBo> responseList, PlatwareResponseListener listener) {
    if (listener instanceof CallServerAsync) {
        processResponseList = responseList;
        for (AsyncHttpResponseBo responseBo : processResponseList) {
            this.responseList.add(responseBo);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In CallServerAsync hold a list reference to all created CallserverSubAsync. Make CallserverAsync implement a finish listener which every CallserverSubAsync will call from their onPostExecute() when it's done(passing the CallserverSubAsync instance). In the implemented method in CallserverAsync remove the received CallserverSubAsync instance(the parameter) from the previous list, also iterate over that list and check if it isn't empty. If it is empty then all sub task have done their work and you should call the main listener, otherwise do nothing as you have task still doing stuff.

Comment: @Luksprog can you please reply with code snippet ?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid